# How to check if sprite in group is colliding with others within its group?

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to check if a pygame sprite in a pygame group is colliding with other sprites inside of its group?

Here is my code so far:

```
def update(self, blocks):
    if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, blocks):
        self.rect.y += 1
```

This update function is in every block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the sprite group, check if `self != block` first and use `Rect.colliderect` for the collision detection.

```
for block in blocks:
    if self != block and self.rect.colliderect(block.rect):
        # Do something for every collided block.
```

Or to see if any sprite has collided with `self`.

```
collided = any(self.rect.colliderect(block.rect)
               for block in blocks if self != block)
```

---

You can also write a custom `collided` callback function for `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` or `spritecollideany` if you want.

```
# Define this in the global scope or add it as a class method.
def collided(sprite, other):
    return sprite != other and sprite.rect.colliderect(other.rect)
```

Then in your main loop pass your `collided` callback function to `spritecollideany`:

```
if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, blocks, collided):
```